# Gaussian Elimination with factorization

Tags: diagrams

I want to plot this figure in Latex. What must I do?
[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsQAXx_ao0

Comment: It is not an right answer to my question!

Comment: You are right! It was a somewhat ironic way to ask you to provide what ever attempts (and failures) you already have, so that we can help you out!

Comment: Have you read the tikz manual (parts of it) yet?

Comment: Not that this is not a good way of visualizing elimination. This is more like a block elimination instead use entries with `0` and `\times`

Comment: The simple way would be to use `includegraphics` to include the figure you have pasted here.  The harder way is to learn TikZ or one of the other Latex-friendly drawing systems.  There's nothing difficult in your drawing that you could not do with either Tikz or PSTricks or Asymptote or Metapost.

Comment: Some of the examples [on this page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/mathematics/) might provide a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupplots` library for `pgfplots` to form a grid of subplots. Then you can use the options `area style` to fill the area under a graph and `const plot` to draw the zigzag line easier.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot} [
      group style={group size = 2 by 2,},
      area style,
      hide axis,
      enlarge x limits=false,
      xmax=5,xmin=0,ymax=5,ymin=0,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[const plot,]
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=green!64!blue] coordinates {
      (0,5) (4,5)
    } \closedcycle
    ;
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=magenta] coordinates {
      (4,5) (5,5)
    } \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(3,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$A$};
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(4.5,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$b$};

    \nextgroupplot[const plot,]
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=green!64!blue] coordinates {
      (0,5) (4,5)
    } \closedcycle
    ;
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=magenta] coordinates {
      (4,5) (5,5)
    } \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=white] coordinates {
      (0,4) (1,4)
    } \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(3,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$A^{(1)}$};
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(4.5,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$b^{(1)}$};

    \nextgroupplot[const plot,]
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=green!64!blue] coordinates {
      (0,5) (4,5)
    } \closedcycle
    ;
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=magenta] coordinates {
      (4,5) (5,5)
    } \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=white] coordinates {
      (0,4) (1,3) (2,3)
    } \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(3.5,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$A^{(2)}$};
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(4.5,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$b^{(2)}$};

    \nextgroupplot[const plot,]
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=green!64!blue] coordinates {
      (0,5) (4,5)
    } \closedcycle
    ;
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=magenta] coordinates {
      (4,5) (5,5)
    } \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none,draw=black,fill=white] coordinates {
      (0,4) (1,3) (2,3) (2,2) (3,2)
    } \closedcycle;
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(3.5,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$A^{(3)}$};
    \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(4.5,3)}
    node[pos=0] {$b^{(3)}$};

  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is there a editor like LaTable for design these LaTex figures?

Comment: I don't know if there is such an editor. But you can draw pictures in other softwares, for example, Inkscape (https://inkscape.org/en/), then include the pictures to your LaTex documents.